# Use Swashbuckle IOperationFilter with Minimal API

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I have my own OperationFilter used to output few querystring fields from a single concrete type. For some reason it isn't called when using the Minimal API.

This is my endpoint registration.

```cs
public static IEndpointRouteBuilder AddSearchEndpoints(this IEndpointRouteBuilder builder)
{
    builder.MapPost("/search", Search)
        .Produces<SearchResponse>();
   
    return builder;
}

private static IResult Search(
    SortingModel sorting,
    [FromBody] SearchRequest body,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Results.Ok(new { sorting, body });
}
```

This is how I register the filter in `Program.cs`

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    // ...

    c.OperationFilter<SortingOperationFilter>();
});
```

For some reason, the filter is invoked but the `context.ApiDescription.ParameterDescriptions` collection contains only the `SearchRequest` parameter.

Note: the same implementation works without issues with old-style controllers.

Comment: The project will not report `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failure to infer one or more parameters.` when you write parameter like this in minimal Api? Model binding has some differences in Minimal api and controller api.

Comment: Model binding was solved by adding the `BindAsync` method to the class. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#bindasync